# Get current browser DOM with jsdom?

Tags: node.js, dom, jsdom

Is it possible to get the changed/live DOM of a website with jsdom?

For example:

**Client**

In my `test.html` file I have a button, which appends new `<div class="p">` elements:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
 $('body').append('<div class="p">new</div>');
});
```

Then I have another button that calls a function on the server (with NowJS or Socket.IO).

---

**Server**

In my `server.js` file, now, I want to count all the appended `div` elements with the `class="p"`:

```
everyone.now.countDiv = function() {
    var jquery = fs.readFileSync("./jquery16.js").toString();

    jsdom.env(
      {
        html: 'http://localhost:8080/test.html',
        src: [
          jquery
      ],
      done: function(errors, window) {
        var $ = window.$;
        var len = window.$('.p').length;
        console.log("Divs: ", len);
      }
    });
}
```

I know that I could count the elements on the client side and pass it to the server. But I am interested if jsdom can access the "new/current" DOM.

I assume jsdom reads the DOM of the `text.html`, but can't access the live DOM of a website!?

Comment: Please provide some greater context. Is the code above happening when you initially load the page (is it the GET), or is it when you're clicking the button in the page (POST/PUT/ajax)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though jsdom allows you to modify the DOM of your templates, it still remains on the server side.

The server side has nothing to do with the client side DOM, or what you call "the live DOM".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at NowJS - http://nowjs.com/ and Socket.io - http://socket.io/ (included in NowJS).

NowJS will allow you to share functions and data from server to client and vice versa.